# Cannot make a slide image in objective-c of Xcode by UICollectionView and NSTimer

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uicollectionview, nstimer

Hi I have a problem with NSTimer when I pass an param to `scrollToItemAtIndexPath` that it has alway be terminated. Have anyone can help?

```
SlideCollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionImageSlideView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

cell.showImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[images objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
NSInteger rowIndex = indexPath.row;
NSInteger imageCount = self->images.count-1;
if(rowIndex<imageCount){
    rowIndex = rowIndex+1;

}else{
    rowIndex = 0;
}
scrollingTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 5.0
                target: self
                selector:@selector(startTimer:)
                userInfo: @(rowIndex) repeats:YES];
return cell;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you're passing an NSInteger in an NSIndexpath variable you need to make an NSIndexpath then pass it to the functions like : -

```
cell.showImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[images objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
NSInteger rowIndex = indexPath.row;
NSInteger imageCount = self->images.count-1;
if(rowIndex<imageCount){
    rowIndex = rowIndex+1;

}else{
    rowIndex = 0;
}
NSIndexPath *indexToPass=[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:rowIndex inSection:indexPath.section];
scrollingTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 5.0
            target: self
            selector:@selector(startTimer:)
            userInfo:indexToPass repeats:YES];
return cell;
```